# Mysql replication trigger error

Tags: mysql, replication, trigger

I have replication master - slave on two different machines (both centos 7, mariadb 5.5).
When on master i run query which fires some trigger i've got error in **Master's logs**.

```
[Warning] Unsafe statement written to the binary log using statement format since BINLOG_FORMAT = 
STATEMENT. Statement is unsafe because it invokes a trigger or a stored function that inserts into an 
AUTO_INCREMENT column. Inserted values cannot be logged correctly. Statement: my_sql_query
```

Query looks like

```
update users set balance= balance + 1 where ...
```

And Trigger on table looks like

```
IF OLD.balance <> NEW.balance 
THEN 
insert into logTable ...
END IF
```

logTable has auto increment column id.

How can i fix this?

Comment: It is only a warning and for that problem you have to do a lot of research see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-rbr-safe-unsafe.html

Comment: change to BINLOG_FORMAT=ROW?

Comment: Generally, `TRIGGERs` should be installed only on the Master.